# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException help maze game

Tags: java, multithreading

I get that error when I try and load a game I started making after copying a tutorial :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Maze.Map.readFile(Map.java:59)
at Maze.Map.<init>(Map.java:28)
at Maze.Board.<init>(Board.java:16)
at Maze.Maze.<init>(Maze.java:18)
at Maze.Maze.main(Maze.java:7)
```

If you know how to fix this error, please help. Here is the code, with the class files at the top.

```
Maze.java

package Maze;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Maze {
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Maze();

}

public Maze(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Maze Game");
    f.setSize(500,400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new Board());

}
}
```

Board.java

```
package Maze;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private Timer timer;

private Map m;

public Board(){

    m = new Map();

    timer = new Timer(25, this);
    timer.start();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    repaint();

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    for(int y = 0;y < 14; y++){
        for(int x = 0;x < 14; x++){
            if(m.getMap(x , y).equals("g")){
                g.drawImage(m.getGrass(), x * 32, y * 32, null);

            }
            if(m.getMap(x , y).equals("g")){
                g.drawImage(m.getWall(), x * 32, y * 32, null);

            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Map.java

```
 package Maze;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Map {

private Scanner m;

private String Map[] = new String[14];

private Image grass,
              wall;



public Map(){

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C://grass.png");
    grass = img.getImage();
    img = new ImageIcon("C://wall.png");
    wall = img.getImage();

    openFile();
    readFile();
    closeFile();
}

public Image getGrass(){
    return grass;
}

public Image getWall(){
    return wall;
}
public String getMap(int x, int y){
    String index = Map[y].substring(x,x + 1);
    return index;

}

public void openFile(){

    try {
        m = new Scanner(new File("C://map.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


    }

}

public void readFile(){
    while(m.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
            Map[i] = m.next();
        }
    }
}

public void closeFile(){
    m.close();


}

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance. Sorry for not posting the code before, but I have never posted code anywhere before :/

Comment: What do you mean by "*rest*"  of your code? You haven't shown us any.

Comment: Please post the code that generates this error.  There's no way we can help you without it.

Comment: Seems to me that it is trying to load some sort of config file or some sort of user input that is invalid.

Comment: I can't see the code, my crystal ball is all blurry... Could you paste it?

Comment: You're calling `Scanner.next` on a empty `Scanner`. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**java.util.NoSuchElementException** is a RuntimeException which can be thrown by different classes in Java like Iterator, Enumerator, Scanner or StringTokenizer. All of those classes has method to fetch next element or next tokens if underlying data-structure doesn't have any element Java throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException". Most common example of this iterating over hashmap without checking if there is any element or not and that's why it's advised to use hashNext() before calling next() on Iterator.

Please post the code to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating over any collection, avoid using the iterator idiom but the more modern:

```
for(T t : collection){
    // do something with t
}
```

where `collection` is a `Collection<T>`.

That might fix your error and others you haven't found yet.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `hasNext()` outside  and `next()` method inside `for` loop that causes `NoSuchElementException`
According to [Scanner#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next)

> Throwns NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

So change your `readFile()`method like this

```
    public void readFile()
    {        
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
           while(m.hasNext()){
              Map[i] = m.next();
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, but nothing comes up on the screen, when in the tutorial, it does.

Comment: Nothing comes up on the screen, but in the video it does come up. Help!